# Can't connect to the websocket server

Tags: javascript, node.js, websocket

I am new comer for websocket on frontend. This question might be stupid :) 
The following html file is to try out websocket. The connection can be successfully established if this page is rendered from the backend web service. But if openning this file from the disk with browser, the connection can't be established.

```
<!-- websockets.html -->
<input id="input" type="text" />
<button onclick="send()">Send</button>
<pre id="output"></pre>
<script>
    var input = document.getElementById("input");
    var output = document.getElementById("output");
    var socket = new WebSocket("ws://localhost:8081/echo");

    socket.onopen = function () {
        output.innerHTML += "Status: Connected\n";
    };

    socket.onmessage = function (e) {
        output.innerHTML += "Server: " + e.data + "\n";
    };

    function send() {
        socket.send(input.value);
        input.value = "";
    }
</script>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The root cause of this issue is the origin checking. If open the file from local file system, the origin would be different from the service side. If disable checkOrigin on server side, then the websocket connection can be established.

Comment: Does anyone know a way to overcome this problem without disabling origin check?